# When a list is saved, i want to send an email to a person entered on the list

Tags: 2013, email

Let me start by saying everything i know about SharePoint I learned from google.  No formal training at all.

We have a list that we created for our technicians, basically a checklist.  In the list there is a field for them to enter their supervisors information, this is a person from the group.

How do i get an email when the list is saved to the person indicated in that field?

We want our supervisors to get an email that there technicians have completed the checklist for each job.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

First, hide fields that filled by their supervisors from users. And make one field which is called Status(Approve,rejected). And do approval list workflow. Like this

```
If current item:is request sent? is not empty
then email supervisors

If current item:status equals Approved 
then email [current item:created by]
```

Comment: If you need to hide fields , I will show you how to  hide . Let me know

Comment: @Kristaps You can create a workflow as answered by Mathew as well you can send email programmatically by creating Event Receiver on the list item.To create Event Receiver visit this link : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5b1f04/create-a-custom-list-level-event-receiver-for-item-added-in/

Comment: @EktaDobaria - I am only providing with [one of many] possible solution, because there are many ways to solve problem above, but only author (@Rob) will know which resolution will be most appropriate for his situation - resolving from code-behind as ER or WF *or* from UI creating WF in designer or setting alerts. And there could be other solutions I did not mentioned..

Comment: @Kristaps As you have mentioned in your post that " I know about SharePoint I learned from google".I thought you might not be aware of the different possible solutions in SharePoint.That's why I have shared it here.

Comment: @EktaDobaria this is not my post (question) - I only provided answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider list alerts - you can sent emails/SMS on different type of events (new item added, updated or deleted existing or all changes) changes made by different users.

Link to guide - [How to create SharePoint 2013 list alert](http://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-create-sharepoint-alerts/)